# What is the difference between USPS label and postage paid label

Tags: label, usps

1. Is getting label using USPS api such as "USPS TRACKING (https://www.usps.com/business/web-tools-apis/usps-tracking-v3-3.htm)" any different than postage paid label obtained from 3rd parties such as endicia.com, stamps.com?
2. Is it possible to purchase prepaid postage on usps.com website, then calling the USPS label api to generate postage paid label? I mean when we call the API to generate the label, appropriate amount to be deducted from my USPS account.
3. I dont understand the use of the label generated by USPS API. I mean, I have activated my account at USPS and now working on production server. Now if I generate any label using the API (https://www.usps.com/business/web-tools-apis/usps-tracking-v3-3.htm), and generate a label. I didn't see any data in my history at online account. I mean, this generated label is of no value? or still my account is not activated? as I think, i have not yet done this -

**reference pdf:Development-Guide-v3-1d.pdf**

> Step 7: Receive Printer Approval from ICCC Implementing the Delivery
> Confirmation and Electronic Merchandise Return Service with Delivery
> Confirmation APIs requires this additional interim step. The NCSC will
> review your labels within two business days. If the labels fail the
> certification test, the NCSC will contact the person listed on the
> submission form directly. If the labels pass, you will be notified by
> the Internet Customer Care Center and you will be able to send XML
> transactions using your “live” data and receive “live” responses. Once
> you are approved to generate “live” labels from the production server,
> and you need to print additional test labels for any reason, be sure
> to use the “Sample” XML request. Otherwise, the USPS will send a
> manifest of the PIC numbers issued to the USPS Postal Tracking System
> and will be looking for the Delivery Confirmation labels to scan.

Does, receiving "Printer Approval" will solve my issue?

Answer (score 2):

Answers to your questions are below:

1. It's different in that you're ordering through a 3rd party provider, but not different in that you're paying the same amount for a shipping label, and that shipping label has a value and can be used in the USPS system. This holds for Stamps, Endicia, and other 3rd party API integrations like [Easypost](http://easypost.com)
2. You should be able to do that entire action through the API.
3. Did you check back on your account? This information should definitely update in your account. Unless you are using an API key that's tied to a different USPS account?

Let me know, happy to help further.

Comment: 1. I am asking for the difference between postage paid and not paid labels. As using the api, I generate the label and no postage paid.    2. Now I come to knew, that its not possible in USPS to buy postage.

Answer (score 0):

If you want an api that prints postage, use Shiprush or another developer tool that is made to generate complete, ready to use shipping labels.

Answer (score 0):

Labels generated using the API `DeliveryConfirmationV4` do **not** include postage.  Per the documentation,

> Please note that the API labels are printed without postage. Postage
>   must be purchased and applied separately.

See https://www.usps.com/business/web-tools-apis/delivery-confirmation-domestic-shipping-label-api.pdf